# summation function prove it is big oh and big theta

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I don't get how to solve the summation problem proving that it is big oh of n^4 and big omega of n^4.

The problem is this:

```
f(n) = Σ(i=1 to n) Σ(j=1 to i) Σ(k=1 to j) of k
```

I wrote the code in C++ for what I think the summation is saying.

```
for(int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
  for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    for (int k = 1; k<= j; k++)
      something bigoh(1)
```

I know that I need to prove it is big oh and big omega of n^4

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not reflecting the sum, as the last part of the summing formula is *k*, while your code assumes a constant for the inner part ("something bigoh(1)"). The code should be:

```
sum = 0
for(int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
  for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
      for (int m = 1; m <= k; m++)
         sum++
```

The innermost loop looks a bit overkill, because it can be replaced with

```
sum += k
```

...but writing it this way you can translate the problem to how many times `sum++` is executed in the code.

Imagine you have an array of values *1,2,...n*, and that you should pick four numbers from it (allowing to pick the same number again), but the order of picking is not important, then you can pick:

```
 1, 1, 1, 1
 2, 1, 1, 1
 2, 2, 1, 1
 2, 2, 2, 1
 2, 2, 2, 2
 3, 1, 1, 1
 3, 2, 1, 1
 ...
```

...etc. You would not count {1, 2, 1, 1} as that is one you already counted with {2, 1, 1, 1} -- order is not distinguished. So we only count where the chosen numbers are in a non-increasing order.

Now notice how the four nested loops in this (corrected) code do exactly that: they iterate such combinations, avoiding to count a set twice (by keeping *i >= j >= k >= m*).

So given that the inner task has constant time complexity, this problem boils down to: how many such combinations exist?

This is a [Combination with repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets). This is denoted as *C((n, m))*, where in our case *m=4*, so we count the number of *4-multisubsets*, *C((n, 4))* ("n multichoose 4"). This number is equivalent to

n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/4!

This is evidently *O(n<sup>4</sup>)*.

There is no way there can fewer (or more) executions of the inner part of the nested loops, so this is also a lower bound: *Ω(n<sup>4</sup>)*

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain non-increasing? Is the n representative of i, the (n+1) representative of j, the (n+2) representative of k, and the (n+3) representative of m, then divided by 4 because that is the total amount of variables?

Comment: My last question is, how did you know to add another variable, in this case m, which calculates the sum of the array? Why couldn't I have had the three for loops and calculated the sum in the k (third) for loop? Thank you.

Comment: With "non-increasing" I mean: decreasing, but allowing equal values. The division is not by 4, but by `4!` (the factorial of 4, which is 4*3*2*1 = 24). You could see those factors *n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)* as representing the 4 variables, but this is really based on a mathematical deduction which you can find on Wikipedia.

Comment: We need to add another variable because of an important distinction to make. The original question is about a *number* (a sum), while the code implementation could be seen as a question about time complexity. If we do that transition, we must make sure to map an increment of 1 (in the sum) with 1 *step* in the code. Otherwise the comparison is not right. Even though you can do `sum += k` in one step in code (you could even do `sum = n*(n+1)*(n+2)*(n+3)/24` in one step and not loop at all!), this would not be a correct comparison.